# Usage Of Marvel API keys in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, api-key

Can some one tell, that how to use the **Marvel API keys** in ***android studio*** for building an app. I did not find a single article that could tell on how to use the Marvel API keys in android studio.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. A websearch for "Marvel API keys in android studio" gets 3 examples in the first 3 results (and more available): https://github.com/eloijr/yourheroes, https://github.com/ribamarsantos/android-marvel-api, http://sanjaymangroliya1800.blogspot.com/2018/04/marvel-api-integration-in-android.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It's simple:**

1. Get Marvel Api Keys (public and private) from https://developer.marvel.com/account
2. Now you need a Hash key to make requests:

- Your will need a **ts** value (for example 1)
- Generate **md5** concatening (ts + private key + public key)

3. Now, you can try in the browser calling https://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?apikey=$MARVEL_API_PUBLIC_KEY&ts=$MARVEL_API_TS&hash=$MARVEL_API_HASH

For example:
Private key: qqqq
Public key: wwww
ts: 1 -> here you can choose the value that you want

1. Go to http://www.md5.cz/ and put **qqqqwwww1** to generate md5 -> result : 30db1167f72b3ff7acbbd14df4c1f878
2. Now, from browser you can try:
   https://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?apikey=wwww&ts=1&hash=30db1167f72b3ff7acbbd14df4c1f878

If you are programing an **Android App**, you found an example here: https://github.com/yelotmany/Marvel-Characters

Answer (score 2):

Server-side applications must pass **two parameters in addition to the apikey parameter**:

**ts - a timestamp** (or other long string which can change on a request-by-request basis)

**hash - a md5 digest of the ts parameter**, your private key and your public key (**e.g. md5(ts+privateKey+publicKey)**

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using a wrong api address that was 'https://developer.marvel.com'

Change to 'https://gateway.marvel.com'

Example in kotlin of how to generate the Marvel API Hash:

```
    val timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis().toString()
    generateApiHash(timestamp)
    
    private fun generateApiHash(timestamp: String) =
            HASH_FORMAT.format(timestamp, API_PRIVATE_KEY, API_PUBLIC_KEY).toMD5()
    
    private const val API_PUBLIC_KEY = BuildConfig.MARVEL_API_KEY_PUBLIC
    private const val API_PRIVATE_KEY = BuildConfig.MARVEL_API_KEY_PRIVATE
    private const val HASH_FORMAT = "%s%s%s"
```